# Cloning Twitter Bootstrap assets into app directory

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to work through [a tutorial to set up Twitter Bootstrap](http://rubysource.com/twitter-bootstrap-less-and-sass-understanding-your-options-for-rails-3-1/).

It provides some instructions to clone Twitter Bootstrap like so,

```
$ git clone https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
```

then, following the instructions, I did

```
$ cp bootstrap/bootstrap.css path/to/app/assets/stylesheets/.
```

But the computer responded

```
cp: bootstrap/bootstrap.css: No such file or directory
```

I looked inside 'bootstrap' directory and saw this

```
LICENSE
Makefile
README.md
docs
img
js
less
package.json
```

What should I have done instead of

```
 $ cp bootstrap/bootstrap.css path/to/app/assets/stylesheets/.
```

?

Comment: Did you traverse the directory structure to find a file called bootstrap.css? Could you provide the link to the original instructions?

Comment: http://rubysource.com/twitter-bootstrap-less-and-sass-understanding-your-options-for-rails-3-1/  I got the instructions in the first or second section Twitter Bootstrap Basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the tutorial you are using was written, Twitter Bootstrap was at [version 1.4](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/v1.4.0), and the GitHub project *used to include a compiled version of the project*, and that included the **bootstrap.css** file that you were expecting.

Since the introduction of [version 2.0](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/v2.0.0), the repository no longer includes a compiled version of the project, and hence does not include **bootstrap.css** until you compile it yourself.  You should follow the directions provided in the **README.md** or the ones on the website, [Compiling Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#compiling).

At minimum you will require **NodeJS** and the **less** package.

If you use the make file, you will also need the node packages **jshint**, **recess**, and **uglify-js**.

---

Your other alternative is to just [download the compiled files](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip), instead of the source code.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that about compiling. I've never done it before.